# What does "Reserve Distribution" means?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm going to install a Linux Mint on a VM under VirtualBox from [this site](http://virtualboximages.com/VirtualBox.Linux.Mint.vids).

I found that LinuxMint 16 Cinnamon 32bit VirtualBox VDI Virtual Computer is not "Distribution Release" but a "Reserve Distribution".

#### Questions

- What does "Reserve Distribution" mean
- Like "Release Candidate", is it a little more buggy than "Distribution Release"?

Comment: The word *install* and *installation* is typically being used for a process of using installation media (usually from the distributor) to build a running operating system, not for downloading an already installed image from a random site unrelated to the OS.

Comment: You should probably ask at virtualboximages.com, as *Reserve Distribution* seems to be their invention.